# Add Field to Step 2 of Merge Accounts

Tags: account, merge, account-management

How do you add fields to the Merge Account comparison page on Step 2 of Account Merging? There are several fields that we have on Accounts that are not shown in this page. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thank you.

[[image: Example[1]]

Comment: are they formula  fields?  Those won't show

Comment: @cropredy, yes they are. I did not know that formula fields do not show up in that area. Can you link any documentation from Salesforce that details this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields that are not selectable with radio buttons are formula fields.  The reason they are not included is because, by definition, they are derived from fields provided by user, API, workflow/process builder/visual flow and/or APEX field value setting.

This, the merge UI selects the winning updateable fields, executes the merge, and the next time you view the record, the formula fields recalculate for purposes of rendering the view.

While it certainly would be handy to see formula fields in the merge UI display to help better understand which column's field values should be selected as merge winners, this is not how SFDC designed this.

Comment: Understood. I agree that it would be handy to see them, as some of them are the result of convoluted formulas that, without seeing the output of, one cannot make the same reasonable deductions about those records. However, I appreciate your detail here.

Comment: @TamimJ - yet another reason for multiple large monitors at your workspace so you can compare one record to another without anything being hidden :-)